# Have Android contains number selection control?

Tags: android, android-controls, android-number-picker

I want to use some dialog control like [this](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-confirmation-dialogs) (image with calendar or time dialog): number selection dialog.User can select one of set of numbers (0-9) and the latest choise will be commit.

Have Android some controls like i want? Or i should implement is itself?

P.S. like this:

[image: only set of numbers]

Only set of numbers,not a calendar.

Comment: Try this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: @VarunKumar, i see that, but it seems that user view only current value, not all of them. Can NumberPicker show all diapason of numbers? For example:0 to 9?

Comment: @VarunKumar, update question

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to create it yourself. I cannot find any way to change the look of the default NumberPicker.